# ELMAH: Only sending specific exception type via mail

Tags: c#, asp.net, elmah

I have ELMAH set up for a webapp, logging exceptions to a SQL server.

I wish to have ELMAH send me an email too, but only when a specific exception is thrown (ie. *MySpecialException*).

ELMAH must still log all exceptions to SQL server.

I know you can do it programmatically in global.asax, but I'd prefer to use web.config.

So, how do I restrict ELMAH error mails to filter out everything but a specific exception type, using web.config?

**UPDATE**

The filter ended up looking like this:

```
<test>
    <and>
        <not>
            <is-type binding="Exception" type="MyApp.MySpecialException" />
        </not>
        <regex binding="FilterSourceType.Name" pattern="mail" caseSensitive="false"/>
    </and>
</test>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its certainly possible to do. Check out the filtering documentation for [elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/ErrorFiltering#Filtering_By_Source).

In particular look at the section Filtering By Source

```
<elmah>
...
<errorFilter>
    <test>
        <and>
            <equal binding="HttpStatusCode" value="404" type="Int32" />
            <regex binding="FilterSourceType.Name" pattern="mail" />
        </and>
    </test>
</errorFilter>
```

Comment: Have looked at the documentation. Afraid I need more help than that.

I'm stuck at this: 

<and>
   <not binding="Exception" pattern="StackOverflow" />
   <not binding="FilterSourceType.Name" pattern="mail" />
</and>

.. which does not work.

Comment: This could be for a number of reasons. Have you added ErrorFilterModule to the HttpModules? Might be an idea to add all of your elmah configuration to your post.

Comment: This question may also help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788900/filter-on-exception-text-in-elmah